# SQL Server 2008 - Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```sql
create table [temp](
[id] [nvarchar](10) not null,
[name] [nvarchar](50) not null,
[info1] [nvarchar](50) not null,
[info2] [nvarchar](50) not null,
[info3] [nvarchar](50) not null);

insert into temp(id,name,info1,info2,info3) values ('id1','name1','infoa','infob','infoc');
insert into temp(id,name,info1,info2,info3) values ('id1','name1','infox','infod','infoc');
insert into temp(id,name,info1,info2,info3) values ('id1','name1','infoz','infob','infoc');
```

Table looks as follow

```sql
temp table  
id         name   info1     info2     info3  
id1        name1  infoa     infob     infoc  
id1        name1  infox     infod     infoc  
id1        name1  infoy     infob     infoc
```

multiple rows from the temp table will be grouped by id, name and all unique info columns will be concatenated   expected output

```sql
 id   name    info1              info2         info3  
 id1  name1   infoa;infox;infoy  infob;infod   infoc
```

Comment: format the output correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select [id],[name],
    stuff((select distinct ',' + CAST(t2.[info1] as varchar(10))
     from [temp] t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') info1,
     stuff((select distinct ',' + CAST(t3.[info2] as varchar(10))
     from [temp] t3 where t1.id = t3.id and t1.name = t3.name
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') info2,
     stuff((select distinct ',' + CAST(t4.[info3] as varchar(10))
     from [temp] t4 where t1.id = t4.id and t1.name = t4.name
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') info3
from [temp] t1
group by id,Name
```

**Function Used**

1. [Stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)
2. [For XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)
3. [Group by](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)